# how to hide the echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey)

Tags: html, recaptcha

How do i hide the value of one or zero in google recaptha on this function

```
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey)// it returns a 0 or 1 value
```

after that it will show the recaptcha box.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other code interfering? I used reCAPTCHA in the past and I've never had such a trouble.

Comment: please i tried everything, it is still on my localhost and it displays 1 if there is internet or not.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make changes to the google reCAPTCHA library files? Could you also please show us your whole code